# jQuery hiding and toggling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

I have multiple rows of `article` and inside it I have `.article-row` with `.content` inside it and then `.article-row` is clicked. the current jQuery will find the `.content` and then toggle it. But I would like to change the code so that it would `.hide()` all instances of `.content` that are not related to the clicked one

```
$('.article-row').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('.content').toggle();
});
```

```
<article class="feed1 entry">
    <span class="article-row">
        <span class="article-row-title">I am the title</span>
        <span class="article-row-date">Sat, 07 Sep 2013 02:13:35 -0700</span>
    </span>
    <div class="content">
        <p>I AM THE CONTENT</p>
    </div>
</article>
```

Link [`Here`](http://jsfiddle.net/subhash9/7TcWM/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            $('.article-row').click(function(){
                if($(this).parent().find('.content').is(':visible')){
                    $('.content').hide();
                }else{
                    $('.content').hide();
                    $(this).parent().find('.content').show();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.article-row').click(function(){
    if($(this).parent().find('.content').is(':visible')){
        $('.content').hide();
        $(this).parent().find('.content').show();
    }
});
```

Hide all elements, then display the clicked one. But first verify if the clicked article is not already the active one to make sure it doesn't flicker or look weird if you animate the transition.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't be cleaner this way?

```
$('article.entry').on('click', '.article-row', function () {
    $(this).siblings('.content').show();
    $('.content').hide();
});
```